# Devise logout link doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Why click on link `= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete` make `GET` request to `/users/sign_out` and render `show view` of `UsersController`? My `routes.rb` is:

```
devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    member do
      get 'profile'
      get 'purchases'
      get 'mailing'
    end
  end
```

and `/config/initializers/devise.rb` contain `config.sign_out_via = :delete`, rake routes output is:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
               user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
          user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
      new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
 edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                        PATCH  /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                        PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                        DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
           profile_user GET    /users/:id/profile(.:format)           users#profile
         purchases_user GET    /users/:id/purchases(.:format)         users#purchases
           mailing_user GET    /users/:id/mailing(.:format)           users#mailing
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
```

Comment: please share routes file.

Comment: i will defiantly solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html generated for your logout link is as follows:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete"></a>
```

This will only work if the js files are properly loaded ( I think it needs jquery_ujs )
Otherwise it defaults to a GET request.

Comment: I add `= javascript_include_tag "jquery_ujs"` to my layout and now it works.

Comment: Sorry, now GET /users/sign_in route me to me users#show action :(

Comment: did you change your routes file? If it's the same as what you posted in the question above it should work. You should consider renaming your users#show route to users#display or something. This is causing the conflict.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake in routes file, i put `devise_for: users` after `resources :users ..` and it cause a problem. Now It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should be work for you.

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: If you got any error then please share the console error here.

Comment: Your solution is the same as first line of my post. Please, read my post carefully!